# Cannot Figure Out PWM Overlay for BeagleBone Green Wireless

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboard, device-tree

I am new to BeagleBone Green Wireless (BBGW).  I just read Derek Molloy's *Exploring BeagleBone*.  Very good read, however, BBGW has Linux 4.4.9-ti-r25 and everything is quite different. Linux 4.4.9 no longer has the device tree source.  Just has the device tree overlays (.dto).  I am trying to experiment with the PWM's.  I loaded `am33xx_pwm-00A0.dtbo` and `BB-PWM1-00A0.dtbo` overlays found in `/lib/firmware`.  I presume these are default overlays for PWM1 but not sure.

```
export SLOTS=/sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
export PINS=/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/pins

sudo sh -c "echo am33xx_pwm > $SLOTS"
sudo sh -c "echo BB-PWM1 > $SLOTS"
```

They appear to be loaded correctly,

```
root@beaglebone:/lib/firmware# cat $SLOTS
 0: PF----  -1
 1: PF----  -1
 2: PF----  -1
 3: PF----  -1
 5: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,am33xx_pwm
 7: P-O-L-   1 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-PWM1
```

However, I cannot find where to access PWM1's properties.  Malloy says that they are in, `/sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_p9_22.15`.  I could not find that directory and the closest I could find was `/sys/devices/platform/ocp/`.  There are several devices but nothing about PWM1.  Where can I find the location of PWM1's properties?  I want to change them using the `echo` command using this example,

```
sudo su
echo 5000 > duty
echo 10000 > period
echo 1 > run
```

If someone knows of a good document that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Hello Fellow programmers -- Don't work to hard solving this problem.  I am close to a solution.  Secrets are in, https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/examples/cape-unversal-pwm.txt.  I will follow-up in a day or so with a complete solution.  However, expert solutions always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you are close to solving it but I got it to work..

Kernel: 4.4.30-ti-r64

Distro: Debian 8.6 Jessie

Now to load the PWM overlay...

1. My distro is from RCN and comes with the overlays pre-populated in my /lib/firmware/ folder. If you have the overlays there continue to step 4, if not step 2.
2. apt-get update
3. sudo apt install bb-cape-overlays
4. Load the overlay into the cape manager:

   echo BB-PWM1 > /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
5. Ensure the overlay is loaded correctly by doing two things:

First make sure it is in the capemanager:

cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots

output:

0: PF----  -1

1: PF----  -1

2: PF----  -1

3: PF----  -1

4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-PWM1

The second is to make sure the pin is correctly muxed to do this:

cd /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux

more pins | grep 848

the output should be similar to this :

pin 18 (44e10848.0) 00000006 pinctrl-single

You can look into the overlay to get a deeper understanding of what is going on but it is a little outside the scope of this question.

if you don't see the 00000006 output. Dont proceed. Reboot the BB and try again. This happened to me and a reboot solved the problem

So, the BB is now ready for PWM.

6. cd /sys/class/pwm
7. cd pwmchip0
8. echo 0 > export
9. cd pwm0
10. echo 1000000000 > period
11. echo 800000000 > duty_cycle
12. echo 1 > enable

Ta-da. it should work. Sorry for the lengthy response. I wanted to be thorough.

I followed the tutorial: http://www.teachmemicro.com/beaglebone-black-pwm-ubuntu-device-tree/

Edit:
This is for setting the PWM for P9_14